# How can I include my generic qweb view on my Odoo 16 Form View using JS or Controller

Tags: xml, odoo

Like i want to show a single summary on all form view do not want to add multiple of time but i cant use t-call because it does not work in odoo form:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
id="template" xml:space="preserve">

    t-name="EcSummaryBoardCustom">
          
class="p-3">
              
Hello World



id="ec_medical_first_consultation_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    name="name">ec.first.consultation.form
    name="model">ec.first.consultation
    name="arch" type="xml">
       string="First Consultation">
          t-call="EcSummaryBoardCustom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the `web.FormView` template

In the following example, we use `t-call` to render a QWEB template at the bottom of any form view:

```
<t t-inherit="web.FormView" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//Layout" position="inside">
        <t t-call="qweb_template_name"/>     
    </xpath>
</t>
```

Comment: would you drop your email i have to share a file with you, facing an issue with odoo16. I would be grateful.